# $.each inside $.each returning last value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, each

I need to put an array, inside every object, then iterate through this recently added array to put an attribute of the object inside every instance on the array inside the object.

like this:

```
 var answer = [];//with three objects in here
 var alternatives = [{id_alternative : 40},{id_alternative : 47},{id_alternative : 56}]
 $.each(alternatives, function(index, item){

        item.answers = answer;
        $.each(item.answers, function(i, ans){

              ans.alternative = item.id_alternative;

        }

 }
```

But in the results I always get alternatives[ any index ].answers[ any index ].alternative to be always 56. I don`t know what exactly is happening.

Would like some help, thanks!

EDIT

With "three objects inside" I mean an array of objects that have other types of data inside, each object inside the array "answer" will contain question_name a string and real_answer an integer.

What I need to have in the end is something like:

```
alternatives = [
    {id_alternatives:40,
     answers:[{
         alternative:40,
         question_name: "string",
         real_answer:489},
         {
         alternative:40,
         question_name: "string",
         real_answer:548},
         {
         alternative:40,
         question_name: "string",
         real_answer:40}
     ]},//with several other objects with this structure, but other data
```

Comment: So what type of result are you expecting in array?  can you put a sample one here? or if you can just http://jsfiddle.net/ your code then it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You are only creating one array (`[]` in your first line), then share its reference and modify it all over your code. If you want distinct arrays, you have to create them separately. For example, you can replace

```
item.answers = answer;
```

with

```
item.answers = answer.slice(0);
```

which is the JavaScript idiom for array cloning to make a copy of the array. If you are modifying elements inside it (as you seem to be; your example is not complete), that is insufficient, since it will clone the references to the elements, not the elements themselves, and you would need a deep copy. It is probably easier to just construct a new array with new objects instead at that line.

Comment: The argument to slice is optional. `.slice()` will work as well.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Yes and no. In practice it is optional, as most implementations treat `.slice(undefined)` as `.slice(0)`. In theory, I think, `.slice()` is [undefined behaviour](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10) (note that it says what to do if `end` is undefined, but `start` is assumed to be numeric). Also note that `.slice` page on MDN said `(start, [end])` till [Sep 4, 2014](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice$compare?locale=en-US&to=661431&from=655615), so `([start, [end]])` for less than a year old.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The problem is that you are using Same declared array for each alternatives.
So to solve this, you just need to move that array inside the loop, so that every alternative gets it's own fresh array.

```js
 var alternatives = [{id_alternative : 40},{id_alternative : 47},{id_alternative : 56}]
 $.each(alternatives, function(index, item){

        item.answers = [{alternative:0},{alternative:0},{alternative:0}];//with three objects in here;
        $.each(item.answers, function(i, ans){

              ans.alternative = item.id_alternative;

        });

 });
               console.log(alternatives);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```